# Should we go Scala instead of Java?

Tags: c#, java, scala

We will be starting a new project which will involve training all the .net developers in Java (frameworks/ECO system etc). We have a lot of code written in C# and it seems that all of this will be wasted as we have to re-write it all in Java. The problem I see is that the first year or so (probably 2 years) we will have nothing to deliver as we will spend most of the time reproducing what we had before but now in Java.

Since our team is distributed in different offices around the world and we have a large number of java developers (20 to 30) and 10 developers using .net, we want to get all the developers using the same language/platform so we can start to reuse components/modules. So I can understand managements point of view.

Yesterday I came across Scala and was wondering if it would be better to use this with the current product (which is written in C#) and then at least we will have a working product in a year. Also in a year we have modules that can be used in the Java world whilst we migrate other parts of the product.

Would this work?

JD

Comment: Are you asking whether you could use Scala to compile your C# code?

Comment: Sigh, if people would stop closing questions they don't understand ...

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere IMHO this question belongs to programmers.SE as it is not implementation specific. I don't know why they favoured closing instead of moving it.

Answer (score 2):

David Pollak wrote a couple of blog posts about this very recently. His opinion was very clear that your team would be a very poor choice for Scala.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/yes-virginia-scala-is-hard.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/scala-use-is-less-good-than-java-use.html

Comment: To sum it up for you, Scala requires a lot of personal investment to be able to program well in. The people in your team are very unlikely to invest the large amount of time and effort into learning Scala needed to get the benefits from it.

Comment: How can you tell they are UNLIKELY to invest time?

Comment: @AndreasScheinert That's just a super summarized version of the blog posts. You can read them for more details.

Comment: Scala is best for people who are comfortable with functional programming e.g. those with a strong mathematical background.  If you have an object orientated, procedural background you can still use Scala, but will take significant work to get its benefits.

Comment: If you've been using LINQ heavily in your c# code, and become familiar with the underlying FP concepts, the Scala is likely the better choice.  If not, you'll never find a shortage of people to complain that Java has better tooling...

Comment: Interesting articles, even though I think Pollak's overstating his case by quite a way to make his point. Also, Pollak is talking about persuading a team to switch from Java to Scala. OP's case is different: he's talking about a change which is going to happen anyway, so the choice is not the relative merits of doing nothing vs learning Scala: it's the choice of moving from C# to a more primitive but fairly similar language (Java) or moving to a more advanced, powerful and altogether nicer language (Scala). If I were a C# programmer I would certainly see having to learn Java as a regression.

Comment: Why did anyone downvote this answer? (I made a +1 to compensate)

Comment: "It's hard to learn sth new, so I'll just stick with C[++|#]" --- I do not think that this is mindset one should adopt.